# Modify/replace GetCapabilities response (GeoServer INSPIRE extension WCS)

Tags: geoserver, wcs, getcapabilities, inspire

I am trying to publish WCS service using Geoserver 2.19.2 (and Geoserver INSPIRE extension). In GetCapabilities response WCS service creates 'inspire_dls:ExtendedCapabilities' in different path compare to WFS service.

```
WCS:/wcs:Capabilities/wcs:Contents/wcs:Extension/ows:ExtendedCapabilities/inspire_dls:ExtendedCapabilities

WFS:/wfs:WFS_Capabilities/ows:OperationsMetadata/ows:ExtendedCapabilities
```

Validation of WFS by INSPIRE validator is OK, but validation of WCS gives error:

```
'The ExtendedCapabilities section shall be provided in the path: /Capabilities/OperationsMetadata/ExtendedCapabilities/ExtendedCapabilities'
```

I am not sure if this is problem of validator or GeoServer INSPIRE extension.

For this moment I would like to modify or replace GeoServer response of GetCapabilities for WCS. Is it possible and how?

Comment: First you need to work out what the correct answer is by consulting the standard schema. Then you can propose a fix to which ever part is wrong

Comment: It seems that both positions of 'ows:ExtendedCapabilities' are by WCS specifications correct. I have found two examples 
1. `https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WCS/HighResolution?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCapabilities`
2. `https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/wss/service/PZGIK/ORTO/WCS/HighResolution?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCapabilities`
and both responses are valid. Thank you.

Comment: @Milan, were you able to solve this? I'm having exactly the same problem with the Geoserver INSPIRE extension (2.20) and the INSPIRE validator.

Comment: Hello @Stevenf, unfortunately I did not find out a solution to this time. There are two issues in INSPIRE github too. https://github.com/INSPIRE-MIF/helpdesk-validator/issues/523 and https://github.com/INSPIRE-MIF/helpdesk-validator/issues/660

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of the INSPIRE validator.  There's no requirement for a WCS to follow the INSPIRE WFS schema.  WCS has it's own schema and own location for adding extended capabilities and metadata about the coverages provided.  GeoServer INSPIRE extension has followed the INSPIRE technical guidance for WCS.

Comment: It seems to that both positions of  'inspire_dls:ExtendedCapabilities'  element are correct by WCS specification.
`/wcs:Capabilities/wcs:Contents/wcs:Extension/ows:ExtendedCapabilities/inspire_dls:ExtendedCapabilities` and 
`/wcs:Capabilities/ows:OperationsMetadata/ows:ExtendedCapabilities/inspire_dls:ExtendedCapabilities`
I am trying to move element to awaited position by INSPIRE validator. 

In ArcGIS Server there is possibility to use external capabilities file.
Is there possibility to customize or completely replace GetCapabilitie response in Geoserver?